# Convert 32-bit integers to 16-bit floating point in Perl

Tags: perl

I am a newbie in Perl and I have taken an exam:

1. Create a binary file having 100 32-bit integers
2. Convert integers to 16-bit floating point and save in a new binary file
3. Add a 512-byte header to the new file and print the contents of the new file except for the header

My teacher says that my `convertIntegerToFloat` subroutine uses too much memory, and that `printContentExceptHeader` function is not safe. Please tell me why?

```
my $name_file = 'binary';


sub convertIntegerToFloat {

    open( DATA,  "<$name_file" . "\.bin" ) or die "Couldn't open file\n";

    open( DATA2, "+>>Float_file.bin" )     or die "Couldn't creat fiel\n";
    binmode DATA2;

    while ( <DATA> ) {
        print DATA2 pack( "f*", unpack( "I*", $_ ) );
    }

    close(DATA);
    close(DATA2);

    unlink("$name_file\.bin");

    rename( "Float_file\.bin", "$name_file\.bin" );

    print "Convert succsess\n";
}


sub printContentExceptHeader {

    open( DATA, "<$name_file\.bin" ) or die "Couldn't open $name_file\.bin";
    seek( DATA, 512, 0 );

    while ( <DATA> ) {
        print unpack( "I*", $_ );
    }

    close(DATA);

    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: `f` packs single-precision (32bit) floating point numbers. I don't know if Perl has native support for half-precision (16bit).

Comment: Maybe your teacher would like you to read 4 bytes at a time, convert, and then print them out.  `pack` and `unpack` will work on your whole line.  What if your line is huge?

Comment: if my line huge, it will appear error "Out of memery"

Comment: You shouldn't use bareword filehandles or 2-argument open. Include the name of the file you're trying to open in the error message, as well as `$!` (the reason for the error).

Comment: Missing `binmode` on `DATA` (both times).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `<DATA>` (i.e. `readline(DATA)`) on binary files, which are not line oriented.

Comment: Missing error check on `rename`. `rename` can fail.

Comment: `print unpack("I*", $_)` will produce unhelpful output: If the numbers are 123, 42, 666, this will print `12342666` (with no newline at the end).

Comment: Missing error check on `seek`. `seek` can fail.

Comment: There's 2 argument `open` and useless dot escape in 2nd function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov You haven't really given a reason why it belongs on Code Review. Furthermore, "belonging" on another site is not a sufficient justification for ruling a question off-topic here.

Comment: @200_success, why should I when they both are written in no uncertain terms in the help?